# When inserting data using peewee orm in python, if the PK is specified, the insert does not work

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

First of all, I am new to peewee and python.

When I created the table with the code below, the data was inserted fine.

```
class Stock(Model):
    name = CharField()
    code = CharField()
    sector = CharField()
    product = CharField()
    corp_code = CharField()
    corp_cls = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = pg_db  # This model uses the "people.db" database.
```

However, if you set the PK, the data will not be inserted when the data is executed with the same code.

```
class Stock(Model):
    name = CharField()
    code = CharField(primary_key=True)
    sector = CharField()
    product = CharField()
    corp_code = CharField()
    corp_cls = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = pg_db  # This model uses the "people.db" database.
```

The part that uses that code is here.

all stock value set.

I'm sorry I can't speak English well

```
for data in corp_list._stock_codes:
    idx = corp_list._stock_codes.get(data)
    info = corp_list[idx].info
    stock = Stock(
        name=info.get("corp_name"),
        code=info.get("stock_code"),
        sector=info.get("sector"),
        product=info.get("product"),
        corp_code=info.get("corp_code"),
        corp_cls=info.get("corp_cls"),
    )
    try:
        stock.save()
    except:
        print("aa")
```

```
I want the data to be inserted into the database normally.
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry,
pk exist need

```
stock.save(force_insert=True)
```

https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#manually-specifying-primary-keys